# How to Edit HTML file?

Tags: html

I am new to coding. I am making a quiz maker and I was wondering how can I edit a file using code so like :

They write the question name and it edits the file quiz1/quiz.html and change the question code

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what are you trying to achieve here, can you add some code snippet(s)?

Comment: Hi, I am glad you joined stackoverflow to ask and share your knowledge. Please go through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to increase more attention to this question.

Comment: Thanks i'll go through it

Comment: Pls state the app or framework you are using and present a sample of the code here so someone can help.

Comment: So if I understand the question correctly, you basically want to change part of your html page dynamically. Read about partial page rendering if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new html file everytime that someone need it, you will have a lot of html files and it is not recommendable.

I would have a single html file and, in this file, call the questions in a form with PHP. This questions and answers could be saved in a MySQL Database easily.

This video is an example that how you could do it. In the same way, you could develop it with others languages like java, python, js, etc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0yamXyN4wM

I hope this could be helpful!

Comment: Which video? I cannot see it

Comment: The answer has been edit with the video link @Striker

Answer (score -1):

Open the file in notepad or another text editor. You can change the code and save.

Alternatively you need to use a code editor such as PHP storm, Notepad++, Sublime Text 3, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to make it do it automatically.

Comment: You'll need to write a small application with a database file